# Mongo field not exist or in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to create a query matching a specific fields with rules:

- No exists

OR

- $in values ['foo', 'bar']

this is my query:

```
query = {
  field: {
    $or: [
      { $exists: false },
      { $in: ['foo', 'bar'] },
    ]
  }
}
```

But I got the error: `Error: Unrecognized operator: $or`.

I know `$or` have to be used like: `{$or: [{field: {$exists:false}}, {field: {$in: ['foo', 'bar']}}]` but I have more complex request based (independently) on multiple fields and this will break the query.

Do I have a solution to do this ?!

Comment: please elaborate how it *will break the query.* ? You can combine `$and` and `$or` to make unbreakable query.

Comment: This problem can append on multiple fields, not only once. And every field have independent request (can be exact value, combination like explained on the post, etc..). and a global $or will have to match everycase :/

Comment: As I said, `$or` can be combined with `$and` to make it less "global". It would be simpler if you add the actual question to the post - what kind of query you are trying to write. With current edition it sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Humm thx, based on your answer I made a test with something like `query = { $and : [ { $or: [ fieldA cases ]}, {$or: [ fieldB cases]}, {$or: [ fieldC cases]} } ] }` and it's working fine. It's not beautiful but it do what I need. Thank you for the direction :)